# How can i figure out the number of characters that will fit across the screen, i get the correct screen width but character width seems to be off

Tags: android, android-studio

here is my code the logic is i get screen width i get character width i divide width by character size and when the length of the string is wider than the screen width i add it to an array that holds all the lines no matter what i do its either too many characters or too little

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
    mActivity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sp = sharedPreferences.getFloat("EXT_SIZE",50);


private void splitIntoLines(float textWidth, String[] textArray) {
    ArrayList<String> Lines = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder tempString = new StringBuilder();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    float screenWidth =  displayMetrics.widthPixels;


    float currentWidth=0;


    for (String word : textArray) {

       if ((currentWidth + ((word.length())* textWidth)) >= 
         screenWidth) {
            Lines.add(tempString.toString());
            tempString = new StringBuilder();
        }
        tempString.append(word).append(" ");
        currentWidth = tempString.toString().length() * textWidth;




    }
   //used to debug
    mTextView.setText(Lines.get(0));
}

public float getTextBounds(){
    String text = "W";
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize( (sp));
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    return paint.measureText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to solve here? Android can just set inputType of your textview to multiline by adding

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

to your layout. Or if you need to show the first line only you can set your textView to single line and add whatever ellipsize option you need.

Comment: Im using the last word of each line for some other stuff

Comment: @DavidCalle In this case, when the text is set you can use the input type I mentioned above and then get the text from each line using textView.getLayout().getLineStart(lineIndex) and 
 textView.getLayout().getLineEnd(lineIndex) Finding the last word will be easy then. To get the number of lines you can use textView.getLineCount()